# Why do I get the error @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable fun when I use LaunchedEffect in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

There are two `MutableState` variables, `currentInfo` and `maxInfo`.
`currentInfo` is updated frequently, and `maxInfo` is updated accidentally.

The Code A can work, but I think that the efficiency of code is not good because `Text(text = "Max ${handleMeter.maxInfo}")` will be launhced  frequently when `currentInfo` is updated .

I read the [article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects), so I hope Code B to improve the efficiency, but Code B cause the following error?

*@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable fun*

1: How can I fixed the problem?

2: In the Case, do I need to consider improve the efficiency ?  or can the system optimize UI recompose automatically to reduce `Text(text = "Max ${handleMeter.maxInfo}")` launhced ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(handleMeter: HandleMeter) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {

        Text(text = "Current ${handleMeter.currentInfo}")
        Text(text = "Max ${handleMeter.maxInfo}")
    }
}


class HandleMeter: ViewModel() {
    var currentInfo by mutableStateOf(2.0)
    var maxInfo by mutableStateOf(10.0)

     ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(handleMeter: HandleMeter) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {

        Text(text = "Current ${handleMeter.currentInfo}")
        LaunchedEffect(handleMeter.maxInfo) {
            Text(text = "Max ${handleMeter.maxInfo}")
        }

    }
}

//The same
```

Comment: You cannot use composables inside a LaunchedEffect. What are the conditions that you want to have Text(text = "Max ${handleMeter.maxInfo}") show? Does handleMeter.maxInfo change? If so, please show how it is being updated.

Comment: Your first code was correct. And as for optimization, your second TextView won't recompose if maxInfo doesn't change. That's one of the major selling pitches of Compose. See the documentation regarding this aspect: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle